# Comparing two .txt files in PHP (~1MB)

Tags: php, html, curl

I'm writing a program using PHP and cUrl to save the HTML of a particular website to a server once in a while. I only want to actually save the file if something has changed on the website, though, so my question is: how do I compare a long text string (the newest HTML from cUrl) against an existing .txt file? The .txt file is approximately 700kB, to give you an idea of size. I'm mo

Comment: Hash the HTML you received and compare it with the hash of the HTML saved on the server. It's just a chechsum.

Comment: @SpencerGrantDoak that will likely show a "false" difference every time if there is a datestamp anywhere in the output.

Comment: Good point, @scunliffe. He could strip away the HTML head and only hash the HTML body, I suppose.

Comment: Unless the page is static this is not possible, at least not in a practical way.

Comment: I checked and there is no datestamp! They are identical. I am going to try this now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strcmp()` is likely your best bet.

It returns `0` if the two strings are the same -

so

```
if(strcmp($savedHTML, $newHTML) !== 0) {

    save($newHTML); // this would be your own function for saving

}
```

Of course, this will not work if there is a minor difference, such as a timestamp that has a different value each time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how well behaved the server at the website you are saving is, but if it behaves properly and the website is coded properly it should return a `304 Not Modified` status if nothing has changed.

I know they are a couple of big ifs, but you should check that before attempting anything else.

See the section on [return values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php).

Comment: Yes, it looks like it is returning 200 unfortunately. But thank you for the thought, that would have been great.

Comment: For this to work, the request needs to contain headers such as `If-Modified-Since` or `If-None-Match`.